What is a "discrete vector"?
I'm reading "Ballentine, Leslie E - Quantum mechanics: a modern development (1998)", Chapter 1 (Mathematical Prerequisites):

Among the very many examples of linear vector spaces, there are two classes
that are of common interest:
(i) Discrete vectors, which may be represented as columns of complex
numbers, (ii) Spaces of functions of some type, for example the space of all differentiable functions.

But what is a "discrete vector"? I could not find a definition, e.g. in wikipedia - Vector. Does "discrete vector" mean those complex numbers can take only discrete values or else?

Thanks for the answers. I now understand them in general, however some technical details are still beyond my understanding and I cannot choose which answer to accept. I plan to read the book further and hopefully decide in a matter of days.

He tells you exactly what he means (and I wouldn't necessarily call this standard terminology): a discrete vector can be represented as a (possibly countably infinite) column vector of complex numbers. Another way of thinking about this is that the vector is represented by either a finite number of complex numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$ or a sequence of complex numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$.
Discrete is meant to contrast with continuous. Physicists sometimes like to think of a function $f$ (from, say, the real numbers to the complex numbers) in a linear space as a "column vector" with "continually-many" entries. That is, $f(x)$ is the "entry" at the $x$'th spot in a "column vector" with a continual number of entries, and since there are not a discrete (i.e., countable) number of $x$'s in the real line, we can't think of the set of numbers $f(x)$ as a sequence of numbers like we did for the discrete case in the previous paragraph.

This gets a little problematic, for a reason I'll outline below, so you have to be a little flexible in your thinking here.  If $f(x)$ is a member of a separable Hilbert space, that means that there is a countable basis $\psi_n(x)$ for the Hilbert space, in which case any function $f(x)$ in this space can be expanded uniquely as a (possibly infinite) linear combination of these basis vectors, i.e.,
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\psi_n(x)\,.
$$
Due to the uniqueness of the expansion, we can identify the function $f(x)$ with its column vector representation
$$
f(x) \to \begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\c_2\\c_3\\\vdots
\end{bmatrix}\,.
$$
We thus have two ways of thinking about a vector $f(x)$ in a separable Hilbert space like $L^2$, the space of all square-integrable functions. One is one in which we think as above, where
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\psi_n(x)\implies
f(x) \mbox{ identified with } \begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\c_2\\c_3\\\vdots
\end{bmatrix}\,,
$$
and the other, where we think of every value $f(x)$ of the function as an entry in a "continual" (uncountable) vector. The notation used there is to expand in the position basis, i.e.,
$$
f(x) = \int dx \,\psi(x) \lvert x \rangle\,,
$$
where I can't even write down a portion of the corresponding "column vector" representation, because you can't write a continual number of numbers $f(x)$ as a sequence of numbers like we've done above.

I believe the distinction Ballentine is making is between finite-dimensional or countably infinite vector spaces, and infinite-dimensional vector spaces that are continuous. He would refer to a vector in $R^n$ or $C^n$ as a discrete vector. Meanwhile, he would refer to a $L^2$ function which was a member of a Hilbert space as a "member of a space of functions of some type."
The reason for the terminology comes from the way physicists represent certain formulas, for example the resolution of the identity. In a "discrete" vector space (really a finite-dimensional vector space), given an orthormal basis of vectors $|n\rangle$ (where $n=1, 2, \cdots, N$, where $N$ is the dimension of the space), you can represent the identity operator as
$$
1 = \sum_{n=1}^N |n \rangle \langle n |
$$
In quantum mechanics, we usually choose a basis in Hilbert space corresponding to the spectrum of some observable (aka a Hermitian operator). The eigenvalues of the eigenstates correspond to possible outcomes of that observable. So in this kind of "discrete" vector space, the possible outcomes of the experiment are discrete. An example of this kind of observable might be whether an electron has spin up or spin down, or the lattice site at which an electron is located in a crystal.
Meanwhile, for a continuous vector space, the resolution of the identity is typically represented as an integral
$$
1 = \int dx |x \rangle \langle x |
$$
Here I'm using abstract notation where $|x\rangle$ could be anything. But, it does so happen that the position of a particle on the real line would be an observable which would be represented in this kind of "continuous vector space." The possible outcomes of the observation of an electron's position along a continuous line would be a real number. So there is one basis state for each possible real number. The space that this kind of basis would span would be a Hilbert space of functions (or technically a rigged Hilbert space). I'm being vague on what kinds of functions would be a member of this space because my interest is more in the physics and usually a naive approach of assuming "reasonable" functions are in the Hilbert space works in applications.
Finally, as an aside, if one were using more mathematical instead of physical intuition, you would probably guess that a "discrete vector" would be one where the components of the vectors were elements of a discrete set. So you might guess $Z^n$ was a discrete space. In fact, $Z^n$ does not form a vector space under ordinary multiplication, see, eg, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091900/is-mathbbqn-a-vector-space-over-mathbbz-or-mathbbq.

It's not standard terminology. It looks like he identifies this as a vector in either $\mathbb{R}^d$ or $\mathbb{C}^d$. In $\mathbb{R}^d$, it would normally be called a Euclidean or Cartesian vector. For $\mathbb{C}^d$, the term - a complex Cartesian vector - could be used.
The term - a column vector - is also used for both.
